# Bat file is not working in windows 64 bit?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have written `batch file` for my project to use commonly for the both 32 and 64 bit environments of windows.

```
%cd%\bin\prunsrv%ServiceVersion%.exe ^
    //IS//ServiceName ^
    --DisplayName="Service Name" ^
    --Description "Service started" ^
    --LogPath serviceLog --LogPrefix=debug.log --LogLevel Debug ^
    --Jvm=Auto --Classpath=%CLASSPATH%^
```

In my batch file i have jvm and set as Auto by default and it's works fine.I have replaced by full path for jvm using following code:

```
--jvm="C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_33\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll"
```

It also works fine in `windows 32bit environment` ,and  its not working in `windows64bit`.`windows bit 64 bit` accepts only `jvm=auto`.It is `not accept` the `full path`.
I have referred this [link](https://commons.apache.org/daemon/procrun.html).They said both are working.I dont know why its not working in 64 bit environment ?

How to solve ?

Comment: Are you sure this is a batch file problem? Sounds more like a JVM/Java problem to me.

Comment: Because jvm=auto working and jvm="C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_33\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll". is not working.mean where is the problem? so Bacth file was not accept the path instead of keyword.

Comment: Are you sure that path exists, and the version of Java at that location is good?

Comment: (It's a little unusual to have Java installed at `C:\Java\`)

Comment: sure.the version of java exists in that path.I have checked the path.

Comment: Is that a 64-bit java .dll?

Comment: @Xyon yes.64 bit jvm.dll.Is that any problem?